# How do you map an interface that derives from two classes in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have the following interface definition in an external library

```
@interface AGSGPS : UIView < CLLocationManagerDelegate >
```

Normally your would define in the ApiDefinition.cs as:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface AGSGPS : CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

The problem with this is that both `UIView` and `CLLocationManagerDelegate` are classes and this breaks down to the following code behind:

```
class AGSGPS : UIView, CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

which is illegal in C#

thoughts?

Comment: I have a possible fix I just tried and am testing, instead of using the pre-defined CLLocationManagerDelegate, I re-defined it in the ApiDefinition file and then was able to derive from it as it is then an interface and not a class, not optimal, but better than nothing.

Comment: Look into [WeakDelegate](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Oct-15.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to "map" the object. The type in the angle brackets is a protocol and that means that your AGSGPS object adopts that protocol.

Check the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html)

Now, adopting a protocol means that your object should implement all the protocol's methods. To do this in your ApiDefinition, just treat CLLocationManagerDelegate's methods as if they belong to your AGSGPS type, eg:

```
[BaseType (typeof (UIView))]
interface AGSGPS
{

    [Export("locationManager:didUpdateHeading:")]
    void UpdatedHeading(CLLocationManager lman, CLHeading heading);

    // etc, include all CLLocationManagerDelegate's methods
}
```

Comment: I essentially did the same thing by redefining the interface in the ApiDefinition and deriving from it, still working on the over all API though so will see how it works out.